# Xdebug 3 with docker container not running

Tags: php, docker, containers, xdebug, vscode-extensions

I can't seem to make my current Xdebug work in VSCode. Did I missed up anything? I tried to run the debug and go to my `localhost:8001` with breakpoint but no breakpoints is breaking...

My `docker-compose.yaml`

```yaml
version: '2'
services:
  php:
    image: yiisoftware/yii2-php:7.4-apache
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ~/.composer-docker/cache:/root/.composer/cache:delegated
      - ./../../:/app:delegated
    ports:
      - '8001:80'
```

My `Dockerfile`

```
FROM yiisoftware/yii2-php:7.4-apache

# Install Xdebug
RUN pecl install -f xdebug && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug
COPY /xdebug.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini
```

My `xdebug.ini`

```ini
zend_extension = xdebug_extension

[XDebug]
# xdebug 3
xdebug.mode = debug
xdebug.start_with_request = yes
xdebug.client_port = 9003
xdebug.client_host = 'host.docker.internal'
xdebug.log = /tmp/xdebug.log
```

launch.json

```json
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Listen for Xdebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9003,
            "log": true,
            "pathMappings": {
                "/app": "${workspaceRoot}"
            },
            "hostname": "0.0.0.0",
            "xdebugSettings": {
                "max_data": 65535,
                "show_hidden": 1,
                "max_children": 100,
                "max_depth": 5
            }
        },
    ]
}
```

Comment: From this step `COPY /xdebug.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini`
You are copying the file from root location in Dockerfile. Modifying step like below may solve the issue. 
`COPY ./xdebug.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini`

Comment: @Subbu I tried, still doesn't work. I double check this file /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini via Shell; the configuration is there.

Answer (score 0):

Solved, I changed my Dockerfile.

**Before:**

```
COPY /xdebug.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini
```

**After:**

```
COPY /xdebug.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini
```

Comment: That's curious, PHP shouldn't care about the name. It is very often called `99-xdebug.ini`, so that it gets loaded after opcache.